# log4net not logging in VB.NET Test project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, configuration, log4net, automated-tests

I am using log4net in a VB.NET 3.5 2010 Test project.  I have been racking my brains and searching all over for answers but I am unable to produce a log file.  I am running from the IDE.

In the assembly:

```
<Assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile:="MyApp.Test.dll.log4net", Watch:=True)>
```

In the file MyApp.Test.dll.log4net (originally I did not wrap with a configuration element, but that didn't work either). The file has property 'Copy always':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
<appender name="FA" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="c:\example.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="FA" />
</root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

In the UnitTest.vb class variable

```
Private Shared ReadOnly log As ILog = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType(UnitTest))
```

In the UnitTest.vb method

```
    log.Fatal("LogTest() runnng test with log4net")
```

However no luck.

Comment: Still hacking away.  I am able to make this work inside of a console project.  Why not when running a test from a test project?

Comment: As a test, try hard-coding the location of the Configfile in your AssemblyInfo file. Most test environments use shadow copying and your dll is copied to another folder and executed from that folder, and hence can not find the MyApp.Test.dll.log4net file which hasn't been copied. (Not sure what the proper solution would be if this is the problem).

Comment: @sgmoore. Thanks, yes your description sounds like the problem. I found a solution that works below.  I'm suprised the log4net config file is not included in the 'shadow copy', given the 'always copy' setting.

Answer (score 1):

The original issue is due to the fact that your log4net file was probably not being copied to your output directory after building the project. You will need to fix this when deploying your app. The relative pathing won't work once deployed.

Just right click on your log4net config file in visual studio > select **properties** > select **Copy Always** from the *Copy to Output Directory* options.

[image: Copy Always]

Build & profit

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out thanks to this [link](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4net-user/200805.mbox/%3C36C0E3BF5460C543B9ED4767D854AFD20BC455@server01.AS.local%3E)

It is running from the TestResults directory rather than where I expected.  This did the trick in the assembly:

```
<Assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile:="..\..\..\WSIB.KCEC.ESB.Test\TempLog4net.exe.log4net", Watch:=True)>
```